# Confusion regarding use of inverse Euler formula?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, signal-processing

As shown underlined in attached photo

How do we get last line? I know how we got 1/2 term, but I am confused how we got the terms $\cos(11\pi*t -\pi/2)$ and $\cos(9\pi*t-\pi/2).$[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\Large e^{-j\pi/2}=-e^{j\pi/2}$$

Comment: Note that it is not generally true that $\Large e^{-z}=-e^z$

Comment: What do you mean?  It is only true/valid for complex signals

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of multiplying the sine by $-j=e^{-j\pi/2}$ to get the second line, you can express the sine as a cosine:

$$\begin {aligned}
x(t) 
&= \cos (\pi t) \sin (10 \pi t) \\
&= \cos (\pi t) \cos (10 \pi t - \pi / 2) \\
&= \frac {1} {4}
\left(
e^{j \pi t} + e^{-j \pi t}
\right)
\left(
e^{j (10 \pi t - \pi /2)} + e^{-j (10 \pi t  - \pi / 2)}
\right) \\
&= \frac{1} {4}
\left[
e^{j (11 \pi t - \pi / 2)} + e^{-j (11 \pi t - \pi / 2)} +
e^{j(9 \pi t - \pi /2)} + e^{-j(9 \pi t - \pi /2)}
\right] \\
&= \frac {1} {2} \cos (11 \pi t - \pi / 2) + \frac {1} {2} \cos(9 \pi t - \pi / 2) 
\end{aligned}$$